# How to visualize right hand side of the equation $\pmb a\times \pmb b= |\pmb a||\pmb b|\sin \theta \ \hat{\pmb n}$

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I know how to visualize cross product but what is the proof and how to visualize right hand side of the following equation

$$\pmb a\times \pmb b= |\pmb a||\pmb b|\sin \theta \ \hat{\pmb n}$$

Answer (score 0):

As for visualization, then the absolute value of right hand side is the area of parallelogram with sides $a$ and $b$. Picture, for example, is here [sharetechnote.com](https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_EngMath_Matrix_CrossProduct.html)

Comment: but what about unit vector n

Comment: And by the way there is no proof of this, since it's a definition.

Comment: the person who found out this must have verified by some proof

Comment: Found out what? There is a definition, if $a,b \in \mathbf{R}^3$, then we denote by $a \times b$ vector $c \in \mathbf{R}^3$ (that called a cross product of $a$ and $b$) such that $\|c\|=\|a\| \cdot \|b\| \cdot \sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$, and such that $c$ is orthogonal to plane spanned by $a$ and $b$. In your notation, $n$ is orthogonal to $a$ and $b$, and since $n$ is unit, the length of right hand side is exactly $\|a\| \cdot \|b\| \cdot \sin \theta$.

Comment: Notice that this description only defines ${\bf a} \times {\bf b}$ up to sign. To fix the sign and hence the definition of the cross product, we require that $({\bf a}, {\bf b}, {\bf a} \times {\bf b})$ is an oriented basis of $\Bbb R^3$ (usually with respect to the standard orientation).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a visual for the right-hand-side of $$\pmb a\times \pmb b=  ab\sin \theta \ \hat{\pmb n}$$

[image]

1) The unit vector **n** is perpendicular to both **a** and **b**

2) The scalar $ab\sin\theta$ is just the area of the parallelogram formed by **a** and **b**.